# How to get Cell Broadcast message?

Tags: android

I try to get text of Cell Broadcast message just like sms, but it does'not work:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle != null) {
        // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            str =msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
```

Do you know any way to get it?

Comment: What do you mean by cell broadcast message, like a push notification, or ...?

Comment: @Jakar - [Cell Broadcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also spent some time on investigation of this question. And it seems that there is no public API to do that. But I can share some results from my reverse engineering research...

My Samsung Galaxy S is able to receive CB messages, so I decompiled SMS app and looked into the code. It has the following `BroadcastReceiver` in its manifest file:

```
    <receiver android:name=".transaction.PrivilegedSmsReceiver">
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.CB_SETTINGS_AVAILABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SET_CB_ERR_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.GET_CB_ERR_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Note the `android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED` intent-filter. I did not find any documentation about it, but from its name I assumed that it's the only broadcast that I need to catch for now.

Then I searched through the code of decompiled apk and found that it uses `android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Intents->getCbMessagesFromIntent()` interface to access retrieve CB messages, which returns `CbMessage` class instance. This interface is outdated even for simple SMS messages, so I assumed that `CbMessage` should work with `pdus` as `SmsMessage` does. Finally I found the [source of `SmsCbMessage`](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/telephony/SmsCbMessage.java.htm) class which is pretty similar to `SmsMessage` by API. It depends on 5-6 internal Android java files, so for simplicity I just grab them from the same site and included them into my project.
The `broadcastReceiver` is the same as yours except the class `SmsMessage` is replaced by `SmsCbMessage`:

```
public class CbReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //---get the CB message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsCbMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)  {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsCbMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsCbMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "CB lang " + msgs[i].getLanguageCode();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
            //---display the new CB message---
            abortBroadcast();
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                         
    }
}
```

After installing my application into my SGS phone with the receiver above, and enabling receiving CB messages in phone SMS application, my app was able to show CB messages in toast in parallel with receiving them by standard SMS application.

The issues are still needed to be resolved:

- How to enable/disable/configure_channels of CB messages in my
  application? SMS app uses `getCbSettings()`/`setCbSettings()` functions,
  but I did not find them. So temporarily I used other app for that.
- How to
  abort CB message broadcast, so other apps do not receive them? It
  seems `abortBroadcast()` does not work here, because the broadcast
  message is not ordered (`isOrderedBroadcast()` returns `false`).

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it does not work in my case. Do you  have any permissions in manifest?

Comment: No special permissions, just the `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS`. Also I had to enable CB receiving in standard SMS application.

Comment: HTC Desire have no CB settings in standart SMS application. It can be enabled only from common phone settings. So... looks like it's just for Samsung Galaxy S. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @GrAnd Are you succeeded using abortBroadCast

Comment: did you ever get the aborting to work? we are trying to create a new "inbox" app, that will receive the messages instead of going to the SMS inbox

Comment: @GrAnd The link u have provided for the source of SmsCbMessage.java class is not working now. Can u please mention currently available link. And I found a link for that class at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/telephony/SmsCbMessage.java?av=h#SmsCbMessage but that class need more and more dependencies with sub dependancies too.

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga get the source from Grepcode and get any dependencies from there too. Just include all that in your project. The poster of this answer also indicated that there were dependencies on 5 or 6 internal Android source files. Grab whatever you need and put it in your project.

Comment: @DavidWasser SmsCbMessage.java class requires 5-6 more classes. And those required classes too requires more classes. I thought this dependency hierarchy will go deeper and deeper upto the many levels. I will try back as it seems no alternative is left.

Comment: @DavidWasser I tried downloading and adding and importing the dependent classes and I see this dependency hierarchy is going deeper and deeper. Already added 22 classes from the grepcode.com sources but dependencies are growing. I wonder how this answer owner Grand and question owner VVS has succeeded.

Comment: And note that I had to change the package names of the source files due to a problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968072/vfy-unable-to-resolve-static-method-10876-android/31024367?noredirect=1#comment50087669_31024367) and that is why the dependencies were so much. I first tried not changing package names and there I had to use only few dependency classes, but as above problem occured, I had to change the package names.

Comment: @GrAnd Can you too please look at this problem of mine regarding your answer.

Comment: @Samitha Chathuranga There was not so much files to grab as you mention. You can look at [my project](https://yadi.sk/d/phROKiXehaeFd).

Comment: @GrAnd Thanks a lot grand. I will check it. But as I see u have used the android.telephony and com.android.internal  packages to include files. I too tried so previously but got errors as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968072/vfy-unable-to-resolve-static-method-10876-android/31024367?noredirect=1#comment50087669_31024367 Look at k3b 's answer and   the first solution was to change the package names. But that solution made the requirement for unending dependencies.

Comment: @GrAnd ok, I did as u told. But now the following logcat message is displayed.( CB messages are not recieved anyway.)

07-04 11:45:10.540  20835-20835/com.app.grandag.cbm_notifier W/linker﹕ library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
07-04 11:45:10.540  20835-20835/com.app.grandag.cbm_notifier W/linker﹕ error: