# Sowing current location in google map android

Tags: android, dictionary, location, marker

This is my google map fragment. It works perfactly and shows a map in fragment but I want to show a marker on current location so how can I show it ? so that when fragment loads it zooms the camera on current location.

```
package canonical.FriendlyMap;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import canonical.FriendlyMap.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);



        return v;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this link and check my answer for the fetch current location in google map [ans link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457634/get-current-location-name-of-user-without-using-gps-or-internet-but-by-using-net/30096005#30096005) there are two classes first is default class and second is how to fetch current location.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your current location in db and update map after each 5 sec using handler and call displaymap function inside handler.So map will update your current location

```
    Marker currentMarker;
private void displaymap(String lat, String lon, String title) {

        if (currentMarker != null) {
            currentMarker.remove();
        }

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new
                 LatLng(Double.
                 parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lon))).title(title);
                 marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_schoolbus));
                 currentMarker =  map.addMarker(marker);
                 currentMarker.showInfoWindow();
                 currentMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_schoolbus));
                 map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lon)), 15));

    }
```