# VFY: unable to resolve static method 10876: Android

Tags: java, android

I used SmsCbMessage.java class in a my program. It was taken from http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/telephony/SmsCbMessage.java#SmsCbMessage
Following is my program.

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.telephony.SmsCbMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //---get the CB message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsCbMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null)  {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsCbMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsCbMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                str += "CB lang " + msgs[i].getLanguageCode();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
            }
            //---display the new CB message---
            abortBroadcast();
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles without errors. But when running it gives following error

```
06-21 23:32:43.530    1951-1951/com.example.samitha.cbmessagespro I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.telephony.SmsCbMessage.createFromPdu, referenced from method com.android.internal.telephony.MainActivity.onReceive
06-21 23:32:43.530    1951-1951/com.example.samitha.cbmessagespro W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 10876: Landroid/telephony/SmsCbMessage;.createFromPdu ([B)Landroid/telephony/SmsCbMessage;
06-21 23:32:43.530    1951-1951/com.example.samitha.cbmessagespro W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41784c68)
06-21 23:32:45.580    1951-1951/com.example.samitha.cbmessagespro I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1951 SIG: 9
```

How to solve this?

Not that I also included all the required dependent classes too when using that SmsCbMessage.java class.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: @DavidWasser Huawei Honor 3c LTE which has Android 4.4.2 (this model has a huawei-customized android os)

Answer (score 5):

if you look at the sourcecode of [SmsCbMessage@android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/jb-mr1-release/src/java/android/telephony/SmsCbMessage.java)

you will see that the class is marked with the **"@hide"** attribute

```
 /*
 * ....
 * @hide
 */
public class SmsCbMessage implements Parcelable {...
```

This means that the class is an implementation detail of android that is not part of the public android api and that can be changed or removed without notice.

[SmsCbMessage@android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/jb-mr1-release/src/java/android/telephony/SmsCbMessage.java) does hot have the method `public static SmsCbMessage createFromPdu(byte[] pdu)` while [your codefragment](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/telephony/SmsCbMessage.java#SmsCbMessage)  does have it.

Your Test-Device does have this class but without the static method.

If you want to use the class anyway you can add the sourcecode to your project and rename the package

**[Update 2015-06-25]**

Since adding source from grepcodes to local project does not solve the problem because it has to many dependencies (especially android.internal.*)

you can create your own  MySmsCbMessage that inherits from devices SmsCbMessage class and try to add missing functions from grepcodes source.

```
public class MySmsCbMessage extends SmsCbMessage {

    public static SmsCbMessage createFromPdu(byte[] pdu) {

         try {
             return new MySmsCbMessage(pdu);
         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Failed parsing SMS-CB pdu", e);
             return null;
         }
     }
}
```

This is still a fragile workaround because you cannot be shure that other devices will have SmsCbMessage

Comment: I didn't use the SmsCbMessage class from SmsCbMessage@android.googlesource.com, but I got it from http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/telephony/SmsCbMessage.java#SmsCbMessage as I have mentioned. These two classes are different and u can see that the 1st one has that createFromPdu(byte[] pdu) method while the google source does not.

Comment: You have said that my Test-Device (android phone which I test my app) have this class, but could it be possible as this SmsCbMessage class is not a part of public API?

Comment: Of course it is possible that your device has a class with the name "SmsCbMessage" but it seems to be different from grepcodes version as it does not have the missing method.. **part of the official api** means can be used from other non-os-apps and is expected to work on different devices.

Comment: Did you try to copy the sourcecode of the grepcode version as source in a different package. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I did so. But now there comes so many dependencies as a hierarchy going deeper and deeper and so cannot complete this dependency adding one by one. (so now I cannot compile the code).

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I have udated my answer

Comment: I will try your workaround mentioned as an update to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is probable that Huawei has customized the `SmsCbMessage` class. What you can do is to use reflection to see what methods are available on that class and hope that one looks like the one you need. Try something like this:

```
try {
    Class clazz = Class.forName("android.telephony.SmsCbMessage");
    Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : methods) {
        Log.v("XXX", "Method found: " + m);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("XXX", "Exception: " + e);
}
```